# jQuery CSS transition animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animaiate a circle in a square motion animation using jQuery and css transition, for some reason only the last css jquery animtion works. i know i can accomplish a series of animations with jQuery animate function but i want to now if its possible to do it with css transition and jquery ,any suggestions how to fix it

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

           $('h1').click(function(){
               if($('.container').hasClass('isMoved')){
                   $('.container').css({
                       '-webkit-transform': 'translatex(0px)',
                       'opacity' : '1'
                   });
                   $('.container').removeClass('isMoved')
               }else{
                   $('.container').css({
                       '-webkit-transform': 'translatex(350px) ',
                       'opacity' : '0.6'
                   });
                   $('.container').css({
                       '-webkit-transform': 'translatey(350px) ',
                       'opacity' : '0.6'
                   });
                   $('.container').css({
                       '-webkit-transform': 'translatex(0px) ',
                       'opacity' : '0.6'
                   });
                   $('.container').css({
                       '-webkit-transform': 'translatey(0px) ',
                       'opacity' : '0.6'
                   });
                   $('.container').addClass('isMoved');
               }

           });

       });

    <style>
    body{
        background-color:darkcyan;
    }   

    .container{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color:aquamarine;
        position:absolute;    
        -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;      
    }
</style>

</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Click</h1>
  <div class='container'>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying all of the css commands at the same time.

You could set them to happen in a timeline, for example...

Apply the first CSS command

```
$('.container').css({
  '-webkit-transform': 'translatex(350px) ',
  'opacity' : '0.6'
});
```

Then set your next CSS command to run a set period of time afterwards...say 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

```
setTimeout(function() {

  $('.container').css({
   '-webkit-transform': 'translatey(350px) ',
   'opacity' : '0.6'
  });

}, 1000);
```

Then perhaps wait another second for the next command (now 2 seconds)

```
 setTimeout(function() {

  $('.container').css({
   '-webkit-transform': 'translatex(0px) ',
   'opacity' : '0.6'
  });

}, 2000);
```

And you could carry this on, remember to keep adding to the time.

Does this make sense?